# Implement a good performing "to-send" queue with TCP

Tags: winsock

In order not to flood the remote endpoint my server app will have to implement a "to-send" queue of packets I wish to send.

I use Windows Winsock, I/O Completion Ports.

So, I know that when my code calls "socket->send(.....)" my custom "send()" function will check to see if a data is already "on the wire" (towards that socket).
If a data is indeed on the wire it will simply queue the data to be sent later.
If no data is on the wire it will call WSASend() to really send the data.

So far everything is nice.

Now, the size of the data I'm going to send is unpredictable, so I break it into smaller chunks (say 64 bytes) in order not to waste memory for small packets, and queue/send these small chunks.

When a "write-done" completion status is given by IOCP regarding the packet I've sent, I send the next packet in the queue.

That's the problem; The speed is awfully low.
I'm actually getting, and it's on a local connection (127.0.0.1) speeds like 200kb/s.

So, I know I'll have to call WSASend() with seveal chunks (array of WSABUF objects), and that will give much better performance, but, how much will I send at once?
Is there a recommended size of bytes? I'm sure the answer is specific to my needs, yet I'm also sure there is some "general" point to start with.
Is there any other, better, way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you only need to resort to providing your own queue if you are trying to send data faster than the peer can process it (either due to link speed or the speed that the peer can read and process the data). Then you only need to resort to your own data queue if you want to control the amount of system resources being used. If you only have a few connections then it is likely that this is all unnecessary, if you have 1000s then it's something that you need to be concerned about. The main thing to realise here is that if you use ANY of the asynchronous network send APIs on Windows, managed or unmanaged, then you are handing control over the lifetime of your send buffers to the receiving application and the network. See [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html) for more details.

And once you have decided that you DO need to bother with this you then don't always need to bother, if the peer can process the data faster than you can produce it then there's no need to slow things down by queuing on the sender. You'll see that you need to queue data because your write completions will begin to take longer as the overlapped writes that you issue cannot complete due to the TCP stack being unable to send any more data due to flow control issues (see http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPWindowSizeAdjustmentandFlowControl.htm). At this point you are potentially using an unconstrained amount of limited system resources (both non-paged pool memory and the number of memory pages that can be locked are limited and (as far as I know) both are used by pending socket writes)...

Anyway, enough of that... I assume you already have achieved good throughput before you added your send queue? To achieve maximum performance you probably need to set the TCP window size to something larger than the default (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx) and post multiple overlapped writes on the connection.

Assuming you already HAVE good throughput then you need to allow a number of pending overlapped writes before you start queuing, this maximises the amount of data that is ready to be sent. Once you have your magic number of pending writes outstanding you can start to queue the data and then send it based on subsequent completions. Of course, as soon as you have ANY data queued all further data must be queued. Make the number configurable and profile to see what works best as a trade off between speed and resources used (i.e. number of concurrent connections that you can maintain).

I tend to queue the whole data buffer that is due to be sent as a single entry in a queue of data buffers, since you're using IOCP it's likely that these data buffers are already reference counted to make it easy to release then when the completions occur and not before and so the queuing process is made simpler as you simply hold a reference to the send buffer whilst the data is in the queue and release it once you've issued a send.

Personally I wouldn't optimise by using scatter/gather writes with multiple WSABUFs until you have the base working and you know that doing so actually improves performance, I doubt that it will if you have enough data already pending; but as always, measure and you will know.

64 bytes is too small.

You may have already seen this but I wrote about the subject here:  http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2008/03/bug-in-timer-queue-code.html though it's possibly too vague for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info Len, now, after I've implemented this stuff, I can really understand your words. The issue is solved. It was simple than I thought, as now I can tell that it's all about managing my buffers, posting them to the socket, and of course limiting as required.